# Get IP from ApolloServer typescript

Tags: typescript, ip, apollo

I am trying to get the user ip address.

My current setup is like so

```js
const app = express()
const port = 5100

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
});

await server.start()
server.applyMiddleware({app})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(` server started at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

I tried to follow this with no luck [How to get client ip address on an apollo subscriptions server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938280/how-to-get-client-ip-address-on-an-apollo-subscriptions-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Passing request into Apollo Server context generated in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056705/passing-request-into-apollo-server-context-generated-in-function)

Ok so basically you have to add

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: createContext
});
```

createContext

```
export const createContext = (req: Request) => {
    return {request: req}
}
```

access in resolvers

```
userauth: async (parent: any, args: {}, context: any, info: any) => {
            console.log(context.request.req.headers);
            return await resolveUserAuth()
        },
```